# Combining axial and toroidal flux

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is it possible to combine axial and toroidal flux , or any two fluxes that share a common core or part of a core?
Imagine I have a toroidal flux through a toroid like core seen in the picture below, then I add a flux coming from both sides of the toroid, the incoming flux is at 90 degree angle to the inner toroid flux and it should exit at the outermost side of the toroid. The field lines of both fluxes never oppose one another like in 180 degrees from opposite directions but are always perpendicular to one another.

What do you think?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, what you show won't work because you can't add fluxes one at a time.  If you start a flux flowing around the perimeter of the torus you also automatically start the fluxes shown on the left side.  Adding the fluxes on the right, then, would want to reverse the direction of the perimeter flow in opposition to the current existing flow.  If you want to reverse the perimeter flow you need to reverse the flow directions on the left and forget about the flows on the right.

Comment: Ok I see , I made a mistake because the opposite fields from each side would tend to induce counter rotating toroidal B fields in the toroid. What if there was no material and instead the toroid would be made from air, could then theoretically the fields coexist with one another peacefully?

Comment: In other words having no magnetic material but air would I be able to have fields coming in from each side and looping back around to their respective coils of origin while having a main central toroidal field unaffected by the side fields at the same time?